# Java Find index of an String Array and use that index to find value of an another array hold that index

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have two array like this

```
String[] StuID=new String[0];
int[] ProgrammingMarks=new int[0];
```

i use method to store data using Scanner

```
String id=inputID();                       
StuID = insertId(StuID, id);    
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Student has been  added successfully.");

public static String inputID() {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
    String id = input.nextLine();
        return id;
}
```

---

```
public static String[] insertId(String[] StuID, String id) {

   int length = size(StuID);
   String[] newArray = new String[length+1];

   for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
   {
       newArray[i] = StuID[i];
   }

   newArray[length] = id;

   return newArray;
}
```

and i also add value for **ProgrammingMarks** Array using another method.
when i use scanner to Enter StuID, i need to print Student Programming Marks.i tried this using another method.

```
public static int PMarks(int[] ProgrammingMarks) {
            MarksSystem.inputID();
            int index=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < ProgrammingMarks.length; i++) {
                        if (inputID().equals(ProgrammingMarks)) {
                                index=i;
                                break;

                        }

                }
            return index;

    }
```

but its not working as i expected. here is my full code so far..
[Java marks management system using array](https://gist.github.com/MasterBrian99/7c626df54a2b6c9c0de928a899c7c276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking the inputId only once in your method then you can try this :

```
public static int PMarks(int[] ProgrammingMarks) {
            String Id = MarksSystem.inputID();
            int index=-1;
                for (int i = 0; i < ProgrammingMarks.length; i++) {
                        if (Id.equals(ProgrammingMarks[i])) {
                                index=i;
                                break;
                        }
                }
            return index;
    }
```

Also, Initialize your index to -1, to handle the case, if you do not get any match in the if block.

Also, If you have to take the inputId in every iteration of the for loop, then

```
public static int PMarks(int[] ProgrammingMarks) {
            int index=-1;
                for (int i = 0; i < ProgrammingMarks.length; i++) {
                        if (inputID().equals(ProgrammingMarks[i])) {
                                index=i;
                                break;
                        }
                }
            return index;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update the equal condition in `PMarks()` method

```
if (inputID().equals(ProgrammingMarks[i])) {
```